# Non stop queries being called even though there is no loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, axios, get

For some reason I can both successfully send the data to the localhost:8000/data and successfully retrieve it from my front end, but when I refresh my front end it endlessly calls the query. If I just run the server, it connects to the database 1 time as it should.

Here's the server.js

```
const port = 8000

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()
const axios = require('axios')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())


const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "",
port: "3306"
});
    
connection.connect((err) =>{
if(err){
    throw err
}else{
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM sg_vod_database.vod_data', (err, rows) =>{
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log(rows)
        }
    })
}
})
})

app.get('/data', (req, res) =>{
    const databaseData = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/data"
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM database name', (err, rows) =>{
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.json(rows)
        }
    })

    axios.request(databaseData).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data) 
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error)
    })

}) 

app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
```

and here's the relevant part of the react component I am using

```
function VODDisplay(props) {

var dataArray = []


    const databaseData = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/data'
    }

    axios.request(databaseData).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        dataArray = response.data    
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error)
    })
```

Do I just have code in the wrong spots? I'm unsure how much should be in the app.get, but I wonder if the front end is just calling the axios.request constantly. I did try to do useEffect to have it only run once but that didn't stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you make request whenever component is render. For react you must wrap your request in `useEffect` hook with empty deps array and use `useState` for `dataArray` it prevents your component to run request after each rerender

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const databaseData = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/data'
    }

    axios.request(databaseData).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        
        setDataArray(response.data); 
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error)
    })
}, [])
```